# Import TXT file from shared folder to SAS using PROC IMPORT

Tags: sas

I am trying to import a txt file to my SAS program using PROC IMPORT.
The file is in a shared folder of my company, every day I will have a new txt and the new name will have the current date
This is my code:

```
%LET IP  = Myiphere;
%LET PORTA = Myporthere;

%LET DATA_SYS = %SYSFUNC(TODAY()); 
%LET DATA  = %SYSFUNC(PUTN(&DATA_SYS., DDMMYYN6.)); 

PROC IMPORT 
    DATAFILE= "\\fswcorp\CTO\DPO\SOIB\GAQ\GER_Atendimento e Qualidade\Myfolder\TESTE_&DATA..txt"
    DBMS = DLM
    OUT = WORK.test1
    REPLACE;
    DELIMITER=";";
    SERVER = "&IP.";
    PORT = &PORTA.;
RUN;
```

When I try to run this program, the following error appears:

```
45          DATAFILE= "\\fswcorp\CTO\DPO\SOIB\GAQ\GER_Atendimento e Qualidade\Myfolder\TESTE_&DATA.txt"
46          DBMS = DLM
47             OUT = WORK.test1
48          REPLACE;
NOTE: The previous statement has been deleted.
NOTE: The previous statement has been deleted.
49          DELIMITER=";";
50              SERVER = "&IP.";
             ______
             180
51             PORT = &PORTA.;
               ____
               180
ERROR 180-322: Statement is not valid or it is used out of proper order.

52         RUN;

NOTE: Unable to open parameter catalog: SASUSER.PARMS.PARMS.SLIST in update mode. Temporary parameter values will be saved to 
WORK.PARMS.PARMS.SLIST.
ERROR: Physical file does not exist, /sas94/config/Lev4/SASPROD/\\fswcorp\CTO\DPO\SOIB\GAQ\GER_Atendimento e Qualidade\Myfolder\TESTE_300621.txt. 
ERROR: Import unsuccessful.  See SAS Log for details.
```

I can't solve this error, when I try to import an excel file in the same way, it works, but the txt file doesn't.

Comment: Did you see some documentation somewhere that says that the DBMS type of DLM supports the SERVER= statement?  What I see is that is only valid for EXCELCS and ACCESSCS engines.

Comment: If it's in a shared network folder then you shouldn't need to specify an IP or a port. The way you've specified it should work so long as you are authenticated to access it.

Comment: Also, you probably have the wrong `//` ?

Comment: Do you have working code that imports a data set without any macro code?

Comment: @Tom what you said makes sense, as we have code written in exactly the same way to import excel and access databases

Comment: @Joe \\ is correct, I import other files (excel) from the same location

Comment: Is there another way to import txt file to SAS? I've only used proc import so far

Comment: Sounds like your issue is access to the file, not the conversion of the file into SAS dataset.  You need to place the file to be read in a place where the server that SAS runs on can access it.  So if SAS is running on Windows then try just using your existing UNC.  If SAS is running on Unix then have admin mount the shared folder as a path on the Unix server.